# Row as column in mysql without using function

Tags: mysql, sql, select, pivot

I am wodering is it possible to use a pivot table to make the col as rows without using any mysql functions and `GROUP AS`.

Here's the table

```
+----+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |    2 |    6 |
|  2 |    7 |    4 |    8 |
|  3 |    4 |    1 |    5 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Here's the desired output iam looking for. The header is the `id`

```
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 7 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 6 | 8 | 2 |
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Are there only 3 rows in the table?

Comment: @Dexter . . . What could you possibly mean by "without using any mysql functions"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is painful, but you can do:

```
select max(case when id = 1 then col end) as id_1,
       max(case when id = 2 then col end) as id_2,
       max(case when id = 3 then col end) as id_3       
from ((select id, col1 as col, 1 as which from t) union all
      (select id, col2 as col, 2 as which from t) union all
      (select id, col3 as col, 3 as which from t)
     ) ic
group by which;
```

Note that this only works for the data that you have provided.  If you have additional columns or rows, you would need to modify the query.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a7936afbfb4146b241b5f0a24edfbe5c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Are those not functions?

Comment: @gordon Linoff this is great. will try it. Thanks

Comment: @Strawberry . . . I actually interpreted that as "user-defined functions".  But I totally get how that is interpreting something in the question that might not be there.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have 100 id's in the table and is it advisable to do the case for each individual id's? I can see why you said it is painful.

Comment: @Dexter . . . You can generate the code using a spreadsheet or SQL query.

Comment: @Dexter . . . Copy the ids into one column and add a formula for the condition logic in another column and for the `union all` in a third column.

Comment: Is it possible to filter the query by id using WHERE clause.

Comment: @Dexter . . . Yes, that should be possible.  However, you might want to ask another question because I may not fully understand your comment.